# How to have a custom 401 page in React .net core API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I show a custom React component when I get a status of 401?
here is the routing

```
        <Route path='/customErrorPage' component={ErrorPage} />
```

How can i trigger that route when 401 happens? ( or any specific error code for what its worth)
Here is how i would call the api and get a 401 unauthorized. assume that the following will sends back a 401 error. In JS:

```
        var res = await axios.get("api/access/validateme");
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way would be to write an interceptor.

An interceptor is a way to get something to run for every single Axios call. You can read up about them here: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Something like this is what you'd want:

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    if (401 === error.response.status) {
        route('/customErrorpage');
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  });
```

That's an interceptor that will catch all errors, and on 401s specifically, will route to your page. Now you haven't said what routing library you're using, but I all but guarantee it'll have something like `route()`, just a function to programmatically route the user.